# CNF: Recursion in CFGs

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

How can I deal with recursive terminals in CFG when converting it to CNF? For example,

S -> MN

M -> AM | A

N -> BN | B

A -> a

B -> b

How can I reduce terminals M and N?